# UITapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: iphone

UITapGestureRecognizer is not working for me, I wonder if anyone can help.

Here is my view definition:

```
@interface MainDisplayView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In the implementation, I have this in a method which is definitely being called:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToPrevious:)];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

as well as this method:

```
- (void)goToPrevious:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"GO TO PREVIOUS");
}
```

I am testing in the simulator, and clicking in "myView" - but nothing happens.
Thanks a lot!

Edited the code formatting.

Comment: When is that tapRecognizer code getting called? Are you sure the myView is not nil?

Comment: you should accept Islam Adel's answer on this

Answer (score 50):

Make Sure that

`yourView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: Worked for me! Was adding a view programatically and forgot to set this.

Comment: Also check this in storyboard for target view.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you view is not transparent - set a background color:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Gesture recognizer will also not work when view's alpha is very close to 0.0.

Answer (score -1):

Did you link the IB outlet with myView? Or, if you are creating view via code and have other views, make sure that myView lays on top.

Comment: Thanks - how do I make sure it is on top?

Comment: If you do addSubview it adds it on top, as long as you don't add any more views after that.

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin is right. additionally, you can ensure this by calling `[yourParentView.subviews lastObject]`

Comment: BTW my view doesn't actually need to be on top as long as the views above it don't capture touches. I'm pretty sure its not working because your myView is nil at the time you're adding the gesture.